# laptop issues after adding extra RAM, screen flickers with weird lines and many other errors

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, memory, motherboard, multi-boot

- my laptop: Hp 15g-104tx
- maximum memory capacity: 32gb
- 8th Gen Intel Core i5-8250U  Processor
- 8 GB PC4-19200 DDR4-2400 (19.2 GB/s) RAM, 1 TB Serial ATA @5400 RPM
- AMD Radeon 520 Graphics (2 GB DDR3 dedicated)
- I have a dual booted system (ubuntu 20.04 and windows 10)

My laptop had 8gb of RAM initially and I bought new Crucial CT8G4SFS824A 8GB DDR4-2400 PC4-19200 CL-17 SODIMM RAM with the exactly same configuration as original RAM. I placed new RAM in second free slot after that I booted in ubuntu 20.04.

The laptop worked fine for almost 15 mins and I was able to see 16 gb of total ram in resource manager. After that this happen:

- The screen started to flicker with horizontal white lines all over the screen like: [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op2se.jpg) (I was not able to take SS so I am posting this for reference from other ques)
- After that I forcefully switched off the laptop by holding power button.
- when I again turned on the laptop, it beeped and caps lock light was also blinking and BIOS recovery took place on its own.
- After restart I booted in windows 10. It was working fine for almost an hour, I updated windows, run some tests using HP diagnostics test and all tests passed. After that while browsing, whole screen turned white for about a minute and started flickering. Then this screen showed up :
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW0vk.jpg)
- After the above process completed to 100% laptop didn't reboot instead again glitches and horizontal lines started appearing on the screen. So I again turned off pc by holding the power button.
- I opened back cover again and removed the new RAM.
- I booted in windows and ran memory diagnostics test. It showed no error and worked fine for about an hour then I switched it off and went to sleep.
- Now when I tried to boot in ubuntu I am again getting a problem like below(refer gdrive link for video). I am writting this ques using windows and till now it is working fine.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NmHGL5XateXSGOgGwFKAzAUawhoWe5TX/view?usp=sharing

Please help me what should I do, all of my work is in ubuntu partition and I can't lose that. Also, I only have this laptop so I am in trouble right now. I will really appreciate any help.

I have already checked for blown capacitors and I don't think this is a problem.

Comment: Evidently something went wrong with the hardware because of the additional memory. The most you can do in my opinion is clean and reseat the RAM and check for loose connectors. If you cannot find anything, this is a job for the repairshop.

Comment: This work you can't lose, do you make daily backups and test them?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick no I don't make backups, but I am thinking of cloning /home partition to the external hard drive from windows somehow

Comment: @harrymc laptop is working fine in Windows right now and HP diagnostics also didn't report any error after removing new RAM. can It still be hardware problem?

Comment: Anything is possible, but my guess would be some Linux driver that mishandles the hardware. According to Crucial your laptop can handle up to 32 GB. Have you run the Crucial program for it to suggest suitable configurations?

Comment: I used dmidecode -t 17 to check my laptop hardware can support 32 gb of RAM and used crucial site for compatible RAM type. I can't get any other help from crucial site. They also don't have customer care support in India. right now I am not able to boot into ubuntu so can't really check anything related to driver.